# How to use IF condition in storedProcedure?

Tags: mysql, if-statement, case

I am using a condition to lock the login account after a fixed number of attempts with the wrong password. The update portion is as follows :

loginAttempts (INT(1)) is read from login account first

```
DECLARE LoginAttempts   INT(1);
UPDATE login SET 
LOGIN_ACCOUNT_STATUS = (SELECT CASE (LoginAttempts > MaxLoginAttempts) WHEN 1 THEN 'LOCKED' ELSE 'ACTIVE' END),
LOGIN_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS = (SELECT CASE (@USER_FOUND AND @PASSWORD_CORRECT) WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE LOGIN_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS + 1 END),
LOGIN_LAST_LOGIN_DATE = (SELECT CASE (@USER_FOUND AND @PASSWORD_CORRECT) WHEN 1 THEN TransactionDateTime ELSE LOGIN_LAST_LOGIN_DATE END),
LOGIN_LAST_LOGIN_LOCATION = null 
WHERE LOGIN_EMAIL = UserEmail;
```

When I set MaxLoginAttmpts at 5, the account gets locked at 11 (Greater than twice maxLoginAttempts).
If I set MaxLoginAttmpts at 2, the account gets locked at 5 (Greater than twice maxLoginAttempts).

Why is this ? Any help is appreciated.

Here I am adding the full stored procedure.

```
 CREATE DEFINER=`pubuducg`@`%` PROCEDURE `CustomerAuthenticate`(IN UserEmail VARCHAR(100), IN PassWD VARCHAR(40), IN AccStatus VARCHAR(100),IN TransactionDateTime DATETIME, IN MaxLoginAttempts INT(1))
BEGIN
DECLARE LoginUserID     INT(11);
DECLARE LoginEmail      VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE LoginPassword   TINYTEXT;
DECLARE LoginAttempts   INT(1);
DECLARE AccountStatus   VARCHAR(45);
DECLARE UserRoles       VARCHAR(80);
SELECT 
login.LOGIN_USER_ID,
login.LOGIN_EMAIL,
login.LOGIN_PASSWORD,
login.LOGIN_ACCOUNT_STATUS,
login.LOGIN_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS,
GROUP_CONCAT(user_role.USER_ROLE_ROLE SEPARATOR ',') AS ROLES
INTO
LoginUserID,
LoginEmail,
LoginPassword,
AccountStatus,
LoginAttempts,
UserRoles
FROM login 
INNER JOIN user_role ON 
user_role.USER_ROLE_USER_ID = login.LOGIN_USER_ID AND user_role.USER_ROLE_STATUS = AccStatus 
WHERE login.LOGIN_EMAIL = UserEmail;

SET @USER_FOUND = found_rows();
SET @PASSWORD_CORRECT = IF((LoginPassword = PassWD AND AccountStatus = AccStatus), true, false);

UPDATE login SET 
LOGIN_ACCOUNT_STATUS = (SELECT CASE (LoginAttempts > MaxLoginAttempts) WHEN 1 THEN 'LOCKED' ELSE 'ACTIVE' END),
LOGIN_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS = (SELECT CASE (@USER_FOUND AND @PASSWORD_CORRECT) WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE LOGIN_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS + 1 END),
LOGIN_LAST_LOGIN_DATE = (SELECT CASE (@USER_FOUND AND @PASSWORD_CORRECT) WHEN 1 THEN TransactionDateTime ELSE LOGIN_LAST_LOGIN_DATE END),
LOGIN_LAST_LOGIN_LOCATION = null 
WHERE LOGIN_EMAIL = UserEmail;

SELECT 
IF(@USER_FOUND AND @PASSWORD_CORRECT, LoginUserID,0) AS USER_ID,
@PASSWORD_CORRECT AS AUTHENTICATED,
@USER_FOUND AS USER_EXISTS,
AccountStatus AS ACCOUNT_STATUS,
IF(@USER_FOUND AND @PASSWORD_CORRECT, 0, LoginAttempts + 1) AS LOGIN_ATTEMPTS,
IF(@USER_FOUND AND @PASSWORD_CORRECT, UserRoles,null) AS USER_ROLES;
END
```

Comment: Could you give a bit more code so we could possibly reproduce the problem? How are the values of LoginAttempts and MaxLoginAttempts initialised? When does this code run? Is it in a trigger?

Comment: I would anyway use the syntax `CASE WHEN <condition> THEN` instead of `CASE <condition> WHEN 1 THEN`.

Comment: The statement looks like doesn't have any issue, might be the issue with caller session. You should share some more info.

Comment: This again.....

Comment: Thanks trincot. I will change accordingly.

Comment: Salmon : I was looing for 'INTO' in my previous post. Its fixed here.